# YouCompleteMe unavailable : requires Vim 7.4.143

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

my apologies if im asking a retarded question. New to windows bash and saw the vim Plugin "YouCompleteme" and tried to install it with Vundle. However im getting the error as stated in the title. My vim current ver is 7.4.52 anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Edit : I just realised when i just call vim it says 7.4.52 however when i call :version it says 7.4 does this mean im using the wrong vim ?

Comment: `:version` reports the version number, 7.4, and the included patches range, which is what `52` and `143` are referring to.

Comment: vim 8 is out now. I am sure YouCompleteMe will soon take advantage of the new features if it's not already the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest vim so run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should upgrade your vim

Comment: hey ! thanks for your reply . may i just inquire after running the update and the get i need to call install vim again ?

Comment: @WanLiHau no need to install vim again it should just upgrade automatically i just added that line just in case it's a fresh vim

Comment: @WanLiHau i have updated the answer and removed the last line.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer and it did not work, any other recommendations?

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee what is the result of vim --version

Comment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:59)
Included patches: 1-52`

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee you still have 7.4.52 what ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee can you try the following `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pkg-vim/vim-daily` and then 
`sudo apt-get update` followed by 
`sudo apt-get install vim`

Answer (score 6):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

It these commands don't work above.

You have to use

`apt-get -u dist-upgrade`

Enforce the package update the last version, and auto process the dependent package issue.

If you also have python error

> requires Vim compiled with Python (2.6+ or 3.3+) support

You can use

`sudo apt-get install vim-nox`

The vim will support the python with newest version

Answer (score 2):

I used a older commit of ycm and that worked sufficiently well for me. commit  d38ffc54461963c4495fefdd8b0c3d706f72d957 supports vim version version 7.4.52

Go to youcompleteme directory

```
git checkout d38ffc54461963c4495fefdd8b0c3d706f72d957
git submodule update --init --recursive     
./install.py --clang-completer
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried `ppa:jonathonf/vim` and found it doesn't support python ([ppa configuration on Debian](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-add-launchpad-ppas-in-debian-via.html) is slightly different). If you use YCM, then it's not the right option for you.

Actually, [compiling vim from scratch](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) is not difficult.

You can find this compilation configuration [sample](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) useful.

In the `vim` dir, you can run `./configure --help` to see a full list of config options.