# Different vim (-python) in tmux than in bash (+python)

Tags: vim, tmux

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (actually Windows Linux Service, Anniversary Edition I have to admit) and wanted to setup vim to use YouCompleteMe.  I was having the problem that vim wasn't by default compiled with python support so, using the directions at: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source (had to modify config step to use only python3) I was able to build a vim with python (python --version showed +python/dyn and +python3/dyn and I could start vim without the YouCompleteMe error message).

When I go into tmux and start vim from there I get the YouCompleteMe error message again (requires Vim compiled with Python) and vim --version shows -python/dyn.  I don't understand why the vim in tmux doesn't have python but the vim from bash does.  When I do `which vim` in both it shows `/usr/local/bin/vim`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you restarted tmux since you compiled vim?  If not, try that, or sourcing your shell's startup file (e.g. `source ~/.bash_profile`) and run vim again.  I've noticed this sort of behavior before when installing new applications and not restarting shells, wondering if you're seeing the same thing.

Comment: Better ways to do what I mentioned above can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables).

Comment: I'm not sure what caused this.  I went back to default unix implementation, and instead of compiling vim I used vim-nox which has a python distribution.  However, the vim-nox reulted in too old of a version of vim for omnisharp-vim so I had to upgrade using instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896698/youcompleteme-unavailable-requires-vim-7-4-143.  This seems to have solved the problem.